# Images from string function

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm trying to make a magic eight ball simulation, but it's not working for me. The inspector element in Chrome shows no errors, so I'm confused why it won't work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>Project 4: Consistent</title>
    <!-- This part is the function to create my magic eight ball that will randomly give a result, but for certain questions,
    it will provide the same answer always to fool their minds. -->

    <script>

        var answerMap = {}

        var images = ['eightBallYes.png', 'eightBallNo.png', 'eightBallMillionYears.png', 'eightBallAskLater.png', 'eightBallReally.png'];

        //I actually had a little bit of difficulty with this part of the project. 
         //The answer.search method you showed us in class for some reason is not working for me.
        //I worked with the GTF on this part 

        function eightBall() {
            var answer = document.getElementById("answerBox").value;
            answer = answer.toLowerCase();

            if (answer.search(/[r]/) > 0 ) {
                var yes = '../Images/eightBallYes.png' 
                return yes;
            }

            if (answer.search(/[m]/) > 0 ) {
                var no = '../Images/eightBallNo.png' 
                return no;
            }

        }

        window.onload = alert('Welcome to my Project 4')

    </script>
</head>

<body>
<body style="background:#EEEE17">
    <!-- This part of the page will simulate a magic eight ball that will provide at least 4 answers.
    When certain questions are asked, it will return the same answers. This is honestly a pretty cool project to work on. -->

    <div style="text-align:center">
        <h1>Project 4: Booyah!</h1>
        <img src="../images/eightBallTemplate.png" >
        <h2>Magic 8-Ball Game</h2>


        <input type="text" id="answerBox" value="Please ask a question">
        <input type="button" value="Submit for Magical Results" onclick='eightBall()'/>


        <div id="myOutput"></div>

        <hr>

        <a href="http://pages.uoregon.edu/alans/111/CIS%20111/p4/mac.html">Old MacDonald In-Class Activity</a>
        <br>
        <a href="http://pages.uoregon.edu/alans/111/CIS%20111/p4/paramString.html">Parameter In-Class Activity</a>
        <br>
        <a href="http://pages.uoregon.edu/alans/111/CIS%20111/p4/isPrimeLight-jQuery.html">jQuery In-Class Activity</a>
        <br>
        <a href="http://pages.uoregon.edu/alans/111/CIS%20111/p4/string.html">String In-Class Activity</a>

        <footer>

            <p>
                &copy; Copyright  by Alan Sylvestre
            </p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's supposed to return different images for different results. For example, if there's an r in the answer, it should return yes and if there's an m, it should return the no image. It's not doing that right now. I also need to add an if statement to allow it to return a random image from the array if there's no r or m.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything with the return value of your function.

You probably want to assign it to the `<img>` tag's `src` property.

Comment: That makes sense. How do I do that?

Comment: This advice is great, but could someone show me some code on how to this with different variables, so I can visually see what you're trying to explain?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that you are calling the `eightBall` function when the button is clicked and the right value is chosen, but you are not doing anything with it, e.g. appending a node in the `myOutput` div.

You also have two body tags.

Comment: Okay. I think I understand what you mean. So, how do I append it in the myOutput div?

Comment: You first need a reference to myOutput, which you can obtain using the  method document.getElementById. Then you can create a img node using the method document.createElement, you assign the desired value to the src attribute and finally append it using the method myOutput.appendChild

Comment: ...or you can change myOutput and make it an img instead of div so you only need to update its src attribute as SLaks proposed.